# Unicode resource string in ASP.NET 6 MVC Web App

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I have MVC web app with .NET 6 and it is multi language.
Changing culture changes all strings between my languages but resources used inside pure js and script tags do not show unicode characters.

here is one example of my resource in js:

[image]

the result in english:

[image]

wrong result in other unicode language (like german):

[image]

(note: RTL does not matter because I'm working on persian and arabic too)

this web app was working fine on .NET Framework 4.8 but I migrated to .NET 6 recently and all string resources inside js functions changed to Unicode data.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following code to program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<HtmlEncoder>(
     HtmlEncoder.Create(allowedRanges: new[] { UnicodeRanges.All }));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it didn't work for me. I found a solution and it worked find but maybe it's not a correct way!

Comment: I added `@Html.Raw()` to all resource strings used in js scripts. like `@Html.Raw(Resource.Search)`